# Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$, $Y=\{1,2,3,4\}$, and $Z=\{1,2\}$

Tags: functions

Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$, $Y=\{1,2,3,4\}$, and $Z=\{1,2\}$

(a) Define a function $g:X\rightarrow Z$ that is onto but not one-one

(b) Define a function $h: Y\rightarrow Y$ that is neither one-to-one nor onto

for (a) suppose we define $g(1)=1,g(2)=2,g(3)=2$ Is right ?

for (b) $h(1)=h(2)=h(3)=h(4)=1$ Is right ?

Comment: Yes! It's correct.

Comment: @vidyarthi...g is not one one

Comment: @rajendra yes, i mistook onto for one-one. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answers are quite correct.